# Find out the earliest revision of a repository path?

Tags: svn

I am trying to check out the earliest revision of a path.  But the path does not exist in rev 1.  Is there a way to find out in revision the path was created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svn log path | tail
```

([docs](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.log.html)). To get the revision automatically instead of manually filtering it out, use

```
svn log path --quiet | tail -n 2 | sed -n 's#^r\([0-9]*\) .*#\1#p'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use a reverse revision with *svn log*:

svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1